# Creating key in firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to generate a key before setting actual value in collection in Firestore. In firebase the syntax was like `firebase.database().ref().child('myposts').push().key`.

How can I do that in `firestore`.

Comment: Hi, @raju , did it worked ? if so, can you mark the answer as correct ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use...

constructor(private afs:AngularFirestore){}

**pushkey = this.afs.createId()**

then you can do

this.afs.collection("your collection").doc(this.pushkey).add({id:this.pushkey, name: "chris"})

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score 1):

```
const key = firebase.firestore().collection("myposts").doc().id;
```

or

```
const key = firebase.database().ref().child('myposts').push().key;
```

same effect

Answer (score 0):

In Firestore, you can call `add()` to generate a random key to push data.

Example in javascript

```
db.collection('pathRef').add({
 ...
}).then(function(docRef) {
 ...
});
```

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

Comment: Hi, I am using Javascript/Angular.

Comment: HI, is it possible to do something like this    const randKey = firestore.collection(`myposts/raju`).add({});

Comment: yes, you can do it like this `const randKey = db.collection('/myposts/raju').add({`

Comment: It not allowing to use    myposts/raju

Comment: use the ' ' with the reference and remember to use `/myposts/raju`

Comment: Hi, @raju , did it worked ? if so, can you mark the answer as correct ? Thanks